# I cant login to phpmyadmin as root

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i downloaded installed WAMP and i could not login to Mysql. i got frustrated with trying different solutions from the internet. I had to uninstall the app, now i have installed xampp and having the same issue, i created a password in config.inc but it wont login, i changed my hosting to localhost but could not  login. someone should help me, i am losing interest in web development because of this.

Comment: I would like to know the exact error you have Maybe it is https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/14220

Answer (score 1):

WAMPServer installs MySQL with the `root` account but is has  NO password set.

So in phpMyAdmin set Username = `root` and leave the Password field EMPTY then press the `GO` button.

Once you are into phpMyAdmin, you can use it to SET a password on the root account. Then logout and login using the new password.

*i created a password in config.inc* You should not add the password to this file, you shoudl enter the password onto the phpMyAdmin login page.

Anyhow if you do, it is used by phpMyAdmin to login to MySQL. It is not used to set the `root` accounts password.

> I am fairly sure XAMPP also does this